# Confusion about interface & thread

Tags: java, multithreading

we can create reference of interface but not object. but why Thread constructor accept **new Runnable()** that's looking like object.
e.g. Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread constructor is like

```
Thread t = new Thread(Runnable runn)
```

and not (new Runnable(){}).
When we do something as shown below

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

It's basically asking us to implements `run` method as defined in Runnable inteface.

Alternatively we can create a new class which implements `Runnable` interface and implement the `run` method there.

```
public class ThreadA implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // thread code goes here            
    }
}
```

and then we can initialize a new thread using

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadA());
```

Hope this answers your doubts. Feel free to ask if any doubt exists.

Comment: Thanks so much.... i thinks it's enough for me